# Change block size of dfs file

Tags: hadoop

My map is currently inefficient when parsing one particular set of files (a total of 2 TB). I'd like to change the block size of files in the Hadoop dfs (from 64MB to 128 MB). I can't find how to do it in the documentation for only one set of files and not the entire cluster.

Which command changes the block size when I upload? (Such as copying from local to dfs.)

Comment: Not sure if/when the parameter changed, but it is now called "dfs.block.size".

Comment: Why don't you change the split size your map reduce job ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd AFAIK you can't change split size, or the number of splits. For MR2, it is dependent on your block size, and the number of splits is automatically computed on job submission.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I change my answer!  You just need to set the `fs.local.block.size` configuration setting appropriately when you use the command line.

```
hadoop fs -D fs.local.block.size=134217728 -put local_name remote_location
```

**Original Answer**

You can programatically specify the block size when you create a file with the Hadoop API.  Unfortunately, you can't do this on the command line with the `hadoop fs -put` command.  To do what you want, you'll have to write your own code to copy the local file to a remote location; it's not hard, just open a `FileInputStream` for the local file, create the remote `OutputStream` with [`FileSystem.create`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20int,%20short,%20long%29), and then use something like [`IOUtils.copy`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) from Apache Commons IO to copy between the two streams.

Comment: After using the command mentioned above, I tried to check the blocks in the file.  hdfs fsck hvr.out1 -files -blocks -locations. hvr.out1 is my file. It looks like it has not split using the blocksize I specified. Instead it used the default blocksize

Answer (score 31):

For me, I had to slightly change Bkkbrad's answer to get it to work with my setup, in case anyone else finds this question later on.  I've got Hadoop 0.20 running on Ubuntu 10.10:

`hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=134217728 -put local_name remote_location`

The setting for me is not `fs.local.block.size` but rather `dfs.block.size`

Comment: note the new change in hadoop 2.0.4: dfs.blocksize (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.4-alpha/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html)

Comment: dfs.blocksize:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Answer (score 4):

In conf/ folder we can change the value of `dfs.block.size` in configuration file hdfs-site.xml.
In hadoop version 1.0 default size is 64MB and in version 2.0 default size is 128MB.

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size<name> 
    <value>134217728<value> 
    <description>Block size<description> 
<property>
```

Comment: <property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size</name> 
    <value>134217728</value> 
    <description>Block size</description> 
</property>  we have to put close tags /

Comment: Will this update the block size for all the exiting files and newly coming files?

Answer (score 3):

you can also modify your block size in your programs like this

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration() ;

conf.set( "dfs.block.size", 128*1024*1024) ;
```

Comment: How will this configuration setting effect data that is already stored at a particular default blocksize? Hadoop 2.5.2 128MB?

Answer (score 3):

We can change the block size using the property named **dfs.block.size** in the **hdfs-site.xml** file.
Note:
We should mention the size in bits.
For example : 
134217728 bits = 128 MB.

Comment: Are you sure that the size is bits? In your example, the value 134217728 is in bytes, not in bits.