# How to change the size of data chunk in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using the new Hadoop API and as there is no way to explicitly specify the number of mappers (unlike the old API), I need to change the size of the data chunks so that I can control the number of mappers. How to change the default size of the data split in the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669800/changing-the-block-size-of-a-dfs-file-in-hadoop might help

Comment: I don't think that you could do that in the old API, either.

Answer (score 0):

Number of Mappers is determined by (File) Splits 
The split size is determined by the InputFormat being used.
mapred.max.split.size parameter will let you define the split size.